# Disabled product redirect from 404 to CMS

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer

My client doesn't want customers landing on a 404 due to a product being disabled. My first thought was write an observer that would fire as soon as someone 'viewed' a product, however that solution didn't pan out for myself or another dev (who is much more experienced). I decided to go the route of rewriting the ProductController, specifically the viewAction within it. My current hope, was that when a normal 'enabled' product was viewed that things would run as normal, and when a disabled product was viewed, that it would avoid the 404 and direct you to a custom CMS page.

Below is the viewAction() function. Currently, if you view an enabled product it enters the viewAction function and hits the exit;(leaving you with a blank page), however with a disabled product, it never enters this function and leaves you with a 404. Which leaves me with 2 possibilities;

1. I need to find where, if a product is 'disabled' it directs you to a 404 (I've spent a few hours on it to no avail).
2. It IS supposed to come through this function, but isn't because something else is wrong/affecting it locally

> ```
> public function viewAction() {
>     exit;
> ```

```
    $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
    $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');

    // Prepare helper and params
    $viewHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');

    $params = new Varien_Object();
    $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
    $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

    try {
        $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
            if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_redirect('');
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_forward('disabled-redirect');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_forward('disabled-redirect');
        }
    }
}
```

Update** I tried performing the same rewrite on another project I'm currently on, and it appears to be working correctly. Seems the issue is my local project.

Comment: Great question... not to discourage you from asking other good questions in the future, but this has been asked and answered. Check http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/9789/5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just display out of stock products? This is an option under `system > configuration > inventory`

[image]

Make sure `Display Out of Stock Products` is set to yes.

Optionally, if you don't want to have them in the list view either set the `visibility` of the specific product to, for example, `search` manually or write an observer to do so when product is Out Of Stock

Comment: This is actually already set as enabled, yet when a product has a status of 'Disabled' Magento still gives a 404. The only way view a disabled product is to manually enter the url in the address bar. Im not sure if my client expects a lot of people to do this, they just want to avoid the 404, and direct users to an editable CMS page that I already created - the 'disabled-redirect' you see near the end of the viewAction.

Comment: @PRstafki just tried it on a vanilla Magento install and it should work afak. Might be a caching or reindex issue?

Comment: I appreciate the try @SanderMangel, but all caching is turned off, things have been reindexed correctly. I'm now trying to figure out at which point a 'disabled product' view is redirected since only 'enabled product' view attempts seem to be entering the 'viewAction'.